# How to add unit test for enum in spock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, enums, spock

I am having below enum class

```
public enum EmployeeType {

    PERMANENT("10"),
    TEMPORARY("20"),
    PART_TIME("30");

    private final String employeeTypeId;

    EmployeeType(final String employeeTypeId) {
        this.employeeTypeId = employeeTypeId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeTypeId() {
        return employeeTypeId;
    }
}
```

Trying with below spec

```
class EmployeeTypeSpec extends Specification {
    
    @Unroll
    def "validate emp type"(EmployeeType employeeType) {
        expect:
        // want to assert each employeeType name() and employeeTypeId here
        employeeType.name()
        employeeType.employeeTypeId

        where:
        employeeType << EmployeeType.values()
    }
}
```

Here, I am passing each enum values using values() method. but not sure how to assert the name and employeeTypeId for each enums?

Comment: " want to assert each employeeType name() and employeeTypeId here" - What assertion would you like to make about each of them?

Comment: employeeType.name() == 'PERMANENT' employeeType.employeeTypeId == '10' like this I want to assert the every employeeType

Comment: Why is it that you want to test `name()`?

Comment: not specifically name(). want to assert every property of the each enum

Comment: I wouldn't use `.value()` in the `where` block to test the sort of thing you are talking about testing.  I would probably write the test like `EmployeeType.PERMANENT. employeeTypeId == '10'` etc.

Comment: got your point. instead of doing this EmployeeType.PERMANENT. employeeTypeId == '10', I am trying to find the solution with where block to test the each enum values

Comment: "I am trying to find the solution with where block to test the each enum values" - I understand.  The reason I didn't post my comment as an answer is it doesn't tell you how to do that.  I am saying that doing that probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will probably end up making more sense than `employeeType << EmployeeType.values()`:

```
def "Test enum values"() {
    expect:
    value.employeeTypeId == typeId

    where:
    // could have more columns here if the enum
    // had more properties...
    value                  | typeId
    EmployeeType.PERMANENT | '10'
    EmployeeType.TEMPORARY | '20'
    EmployeeType.PART_TIME | '30'
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really deal with future modifications, i.e, it doesn't make sure that new cases are covered.

Comment: "it doesn't make sure that new cases are covered" - You are correct.  It makes sure that the `typeId` has the expected value.  If the enum had other properties, they could be interrogated.

Comment: Just wanted to point out, that OPs test will also detect new enum values, as it uses `EmployeeType.values()`. So you could either make a canary test that just checks the size of the enum is still the expected `3`. Alternatively, you could use  `[value, typeId] << [EmployeeType.values(), ['10', '20', '30']].transpose()`, granted the data table reads nicer, but this will start to fail if a new enum value was added without updating the test as well.

Comment: "ust wanted to point out, that OPs test will also detect new enum values, as it uses EmployeeType.values()" - Right, but there are no useful general assertions that can be made about new enum values without having to revisit the test.  If you prefer to use the `.values()` approach and that is more simple for you, do that.  I wouldn't.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, that at least one test should start failing if a new enum value is added without revisiting and updating this test.